# Как записать из файла данные в переменную построчно

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот допустим у меня есть какая то последовательность в файле

```
-12.453 34.22 
5.435 -5.3456
3.455 -7.544
```

Мне нужно записать первую строчку (-12.453 и 34.22) в переменную a
,вторую (5.435 и -5.3456) в переменную b
,третью (3.455 и -7.544) опять в переменную а,
и т.д.

Уже голову сломал как это сделать

Должно это быть примерно так:
a = [-12.453,34.22,3.455,-7.544]
b = [5.435,-5.3456]

Comment: что должна содержать переменная `a` для указанного примера данных - список (строк или флоатов), кортеж, строку?

Comment: Что-то на подобии координат переменная а это координаты по оси (x), а координаты b по оси (y)

Comment: а что тогда у вас в одной строке исходного файла??

Comment: @MobyFle Можно точнее? Не совсем понятно, что значит _"опять в переменную а, и т.д."_. Она же перезапишется, и Вы потеряете предыдущее значение. Так и задумано?

Comment: [Приведите в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1185941/edit) пример результата для указанных входных данных

Comment: Нет,имеется ввиду,что мы сперва записываем из одной строки в переменную a,а потом в переменную b, потом мы к старому результату (переменной а) прибавляем еще одну строчку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
a = []
b = []

with open("myfile.txt", "r") as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp.readlines()):
        point = tuple(map(float, line.strip().split()))
        if i % 2:
            a.append(point)
        else:
            b.append(point)
```

- `.strip()` - обрезает пробелы в начале если есть и \n в конце.
- `.split()` - разбивает строчку по пробелу
- `map` применяет `float` к каждому элементу
- `tuple` - вытаскивает значения из мапа, чтоб можно было доставать по индексу - заменить на `list` если нужен изменяемый массив

Comment: А можно как то line сделать типа float? Если допустим использовать его где-то в дальнейшем

Comment: можно, добавил в ответ